# iOS AppStore: What order are app updates presented in?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

When an app has a new update available in iOS 14.5 it's added to the available updates list in the AppStore app, and I've always assumed that the newer the update the higher up the list the app will appear.

Some apps with a new update available are added at the top of the list, but others, like GitHub for example, always get added very far down the list (effectively buried from my attention), below apps that haven't received a new update for a year.

We can conclude the order is not chronological. It's also not alphabetical. Is it sorted in any way?

Comment: @fsb Not sure about the answers but it seems to be the same question, at least. Good find. I guess this is a duplicate then.